# Angular JS - angular.forEach - How to get key of the object?

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON object like below

```
{
    "txt_inc_Application": {
        "EWS": true,
        "EWindow": true
    },
    "txt_inc_IncidentType": {
        "Brand Damage": true,
        "Internal failure": true
    }
}
```

And I am using angular.forEach to get the values

```
$scope.filterFormula=function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.filters, function(filterObj , filterIndex) {
        angular.forEach(filterObj, function(value , key) {
            console.log(value+"--"+key)
        })
    })
}
```

How can i get "txt_inc_Application" and "txt_inc_IncidentType" in the loop?

Also when call the angular function in html like below why it is getting executed twice?

```
{{filterFormula()}}
```

[image]

Comment: try $scope.filterFormula=function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.filters, function(filterObj , filterIndex) {
        angular.forEach(filterObj, function(value , key) {
            console.log(filterIndex)
        })
    })
}

Comment: Bindings are called at least once per apply-digest cycle. AngularJS keeps checking all bindings until nothing has changed in a cycle. So if it checks `filterFormula`, and something in the model changes in the same cycle, it will be called again! And again! And again! Up to 10 times until you get the error `10 $digest iterations reached`.

Comment: Thanks. Silly me. I dont know why I ignored that. Also any idea why filterFormula function is getting executed twice? I can see console .log is printed twice.

Comment: Yes. added image in main post

Comment: My comment describes why you get this behaviour! AngularJS must call it again to see if the model has changed.

Comment: @stevuu Thanks. Your comment explains this behaviour

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The first parameter to the iterator in `forEach` is the value and second is the key of the object.

```
angular.forEach(objectToIterate, function(value, key) {
    /* do something for all key: value pairs */
});
```

In your example, the outer forEach is actually:

```
angular.forEach($scope.filters, function(filterObj , filterKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {name: 'Krishna', gender: 'male'};
angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

yields the attributes of `obj` with their respective values:

```
name: Krishna
gender: male
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Yields is a misleading verb here, your code is not yielding anything here, just logging to console.